# Is there a concept of weakly periodic in stats? If so, what is it called?

Tags: signal-processing, fourier-transform

Ok, say we have a signal that reoccurs within every T+x time where T is a constant and x is a random number small in size compared to T. We know that a function is actually periodic if F(x) = F(x+T), but is there a) a word for signals that are "weakly periodic" as described and b) how do we test for a signal being weakly periodic, work out T and the structure of x?

I'm probably not asking this well, my background is in physics and I'm pretty sure this thing happens once a day within twenty minutes of a day, but being able to prove that would be great as checking a couple of years of this data is not feasible for me. I'm happy to take edits and also happy to mark an answer that tells me I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: what is the form of your data?  Are they event times, or evenly spaced samples of a continuous measure of signal strength, or ... ?

Comment: They are event times and signed amounts. For example, I'm seeing a +14 event every day within twenty minutes of the same time. There's lots of other noise in the data, say a few +/-1 events over the course of the day. There's other "significant events", but I am not looking at these at the moment.